# Getting error when adding a function to my react app

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and followed a tutorial to do a shopping cart. In the end, I added a function that would give me the total cost of the products, but I get an error when adding products and clicking on Cart "productList.reduce is not a function". You can see this function (getTotalCost) in Cart.  I tried to solve this but I get other errors. These are my files:

ProductsPage :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './ProductsPage.css'
import Products from '../../components/Products'
import Cart from '../../components/Cart'

const PAGE_PRODUCTS = 'products';
const PAGE_CART = 'cart';


function ProductsPage() {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState ([]);

    const [page, setPage] = useState (PAGE_PRODUCTS);


    const addToCart = (product) => {
        setCart ([...cart, {...product}])
    }

    const removeFromCart = (productToRemove) => {
        setCart(cart.filter(product => product !== productToRemove))
    }

    const navigateTo = (nextPage) => {
        setPage(nextPage);
    };


    return (
            <div className="productspage">
            <header>
                <button className="cart-btn" onClick={()=> navigateTo(PAGE_CART)}>
                    Go to Cart ({cart.length})
                </button>
                <button className="products-btn" onClick={()=> navigateTo(PAGE_PRODUCTS)}>
                    View Products
                </button>
            </header>
            {page === PAGE_PRODUCTS && <Products addToCart={addToCart}/>}
            {page === PAGE_CART && <Cart cart={cart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />}
           <div>
               
           </div>
            </div>
    );

    
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

Products:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Products ({ addToCart }) {
        const [products] = useState ([
            {
                name: 'Breakfast  ',
                cost:'9.99$',
                image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569420067112-b57b4f024595?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80',
    
            },
            {
                name: 'Breakfast box ',
                cost:'8.99$',
                image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569419910356-f63064754fc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80',
    
            },
            {
                name: 'Snack box ',
                cost:'6.99$',
                image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569419882964-7db5d339951b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80',
    
            },
            {
                name: '4 small breakfast bowls ',
                cost:'9.99$',
                image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570649857669-4ad9f896435d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=703&q=80',
    
            }
        ])



    return (
        <>
        <h1 className="products-title">Products</h1>
        <div className="products">
           {products.map((product , index) => (
           <div className="product" key={index}>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
              <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
              <p></p>
              <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
                  Add to Cart
               </button>
        
           </div>
               
               ))}
        </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default Products;
```

Cart

```
import React from 'react'
import products from '../../components/Products'


function Cart ({ cart, removeFromCart }) {

 
    const getTotalCost = (productList) => (
        productList.reduce((totalCost, { cost: itemCost }) => totalCost += parseFloat(itemCost), 0)
    );

    return (
    <>
            <h1>Cart</h1>
               <div className="products">
               {cart.map((product , index) => (
               <div className="product" key={index}>
                  <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                  <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
                  <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
                  <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}>
                      Remove
                   </button>
                    {getTotalCost(products)}
               </div>
                   
                   ))}
            </div>
            </>
    )
}

export default Cart;
```

Comment: `products` doesn't appear to be defined in `Cart`. Did you mean to pass `cart` instead?

Comment: Where you are calling `{getTotalCost(products)}`, where does the `products` come from? You probably want `{getTotalCost(cart)}` instead?

Comment: I thought by importing ```products  from '../../components/Products'``` it would be suficient. Anyway I changed ```products``` to ```cart``` and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code snippet, where you are calling {getTotalCost(products)}, you are using the `products` component you are importing on line 2, which is a Component, not a List, so the `reduce` function does not exist on it, which is why you're seeing that error.

You probably want `{getTotalCost(cart)}` instead.